# Specified a list with shape [1,10] from a tensor with shape [32,10] - LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am working on a future yield curve forcaste using LSTM and dense layer. I am most a financial guy trying to build proof of conect model.
So problem statement is, to build an AI model that predicts the future(T+20) yield curve(its a vector of 10 numbers) by looking at last 20 days of actual yield curve data.

I have prior knowledge of how LSTMs work in general, I have transformed the data from

1001 rows X 10 col to

For dependent data into (961,20,10) and (961,10) for target data. I have written a custom function for the specific need.

I have tried to build a model, but I am able to generate predictions out of it.

```
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import  tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 1
epochs = 2
timesteps = 20

inputs_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, 10)) 
lstm_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(inputs_1_mae) 
output_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 10)(lstm_1_mae) 

regressor_mae = tf.keras.Model(inputs= inputs_1_mae ,outputs = output_1_mae) 
regressor_mae.compile (optimizer = "adam", loss = "mae") 
regressor_mae.summary() 

regressor_mae.fit(final_x_array, final_y_array, batch_size = batch_size, epochs=epochs)
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(1, 20, 10)]             0         
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)               (1, 20, 10)               840       
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (1, 20, 10)               110       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 950
Trainable params: 950
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I try to get training data prediction using this

```
prediction = regressor_mae.predict(final_x_array)
```

I am getting the below error

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_240372/2358700359.py in <module>
----> 1 prediction = regressor_mae.predict(final_x_array)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Specified a list with shape [1,10] from a tensor with shape [32,10]
     [[{{node TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
     [[model_1/lstm_2/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_20772]
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or if you have any suggestions of better models architecture.

I have attached my input and target array as .npy files

[Input Data](https://x0.at/lMxr.npy)

[Target Data](https://x0.at/G9vi.npy)

Thank you

Comment: on `predict` need to feed the batch size, to reproduce with ease,  pls  provide some sample data for `final_x_array` and  `final_y_array`

Comment: Sample data have added. Thanks alot.

Comment: pls try `prediction = regressor_mae.predict(final_x_array,batch_size)`, note: not analyzed the data, but it would remove the error.